# сигнатура метода в классе в php

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что за добавка `:string` в методе ? Или где можно почитать об этом ?

```
public function editName(Request $request): string
{
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это указание типа выходного значения у метода/функции. (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.declarations.php)

Нужно это как для подсказок программистам, чтобы они знали, что функция ожидает и возвращает, так и для соблюдения строгой типизации

Comment: type hinting доступен начиная с php7